# How to clone and print the window in javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to print the screen but I want to modify it before printing as I do not want one logo to be printed. But somehow my code is not working, can you please help in that.

```js
var printContents = $('body').html();
printContents = $(printContents).find('.mccp-logo').remove();
var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
window.print();
document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
```

When I print above code it prints [object][object]

Comment: `$('body').html()` gives you a string, not the current DOM, and `remove()` does not return what you think it does.

Comment: So what code I should write in JS ?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to do this with CSS:

```css
@media print
{    
    .mccp-logo
    {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

But if you want to do it with JS:

```js
var printContents = $('body');
printContents.find('.mccp-logo').css('visibility', 'hidden');
window.print();
printContents.find('.mccp-logo').css('visibility', 'visible');
```

Comment: Edited the answer